# JPA 2.0 with Weblogic 10.3.5 Eclipselink issue - This version of OpenJPA cannot read a persistence.xml document

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, weblogic-10.x

JPA 2.0 "seems" to be finally working in my application deployed on Weblogic 10.3.5 (after tweaks described below).

However, I still get the following message on the WL console terminal:

```
This version of OpenJPA cannot read a persistence.xml document with a version different from "1.0". Found: version "2.0" in
```

This is appearing more than once in the logs and I am looking at some way to get rid of it. Read somewhere that this happens with WL 11g release but is there a way to hide/do away or fix it?

Environment:

Weblogic 10.3.5

- Toplink configured as default persistence provider in console
- WL classpath modified to have jpa2 specific jars in WL in front of the path (as described in [Toplink with Weblogic 10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#CIHDGHFE))

Removed Toplink jars from application.

Answer (score 0):

We've used the Oracle patch to configure JPA2 on WLS 10.3.5
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/using_toplink.htm#CIHIBGBG
Looks as if Kodo is using openJPA.  You might consider configuring Toplink in your console.